# Python Flask download/upload database table in cvs/xlsx format

Tags: python, flask, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I have a download button on my flask app and i am trying to add functionality that will allow user to download all data from books table locally in csv or excel format.

Another thing i would like to do is to upload excel or csv file and import the data in books table.

For download i have this

```
@admin_role.route('/download')
@login_required
def post():
    si = StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    for book in Book.query.all():
        cw.writerows(book)
    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```

But i have error `TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable`

this is the model:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    """
    Create a Books table
    """

    __tablename__ = 'books'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True,unique=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('departments.id'))
    employees_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employees.id'))
    publisher = db.Column(db.String(200))
    no_of_pgs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pbs_year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    genre_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('genres.id'), nullable=False)
    read = db.Column(db.Enum('NO', 'YES'), default='NO')

    borrows = db.relationship('Borrow', backref='book',
                                lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 2):

`writerows` is expecting an iterable, which is to say, a list, tuple, or other [iterable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration). Looking over your code, it's clear to me that one problem is, you don't know what columns you're writing. For example, suppose you wanted to export `id`, `book_name`, and `author`:

```py
cw = csv.writer(si)
cw.writerow(['id', 'book_name', 'author'])    # Write header row
for book in Book.query.all():
    cw.writerows([str(book.id), book.book_name, book.author])
```

Perhaps more elegantly, you can avoid repeating yourself:

```
export_columns = ['id', 'book_name', 'author']

cw = csv.writer(si)
cw.writerow(export_columns)
for book in Book.query.all():
    cw.writerows([str(getattr(book, col)) for col in export_columns])
```

Note that I'm explicitly casting all columns to a string. If you have Unicode in your database, you'll need to figure out how you want to encode those strings, but that's another topic.

In terms of actually sending the file to the user, you'll want to use the Flask [send_file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file) function.

```py
from flask import send_file

si.seek(0)
return send_file(si, attachment_filename='export.csv', as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: I tried the solution but it returns empty CSV. Do you maybe know why

Comment: Is books returning rows? Alternatively, maybe call si.flush() after you finish?? I'm not sure.

Comment: books are returning rows but for some reason code you proposed is not working. I also tried using flush()

Comment: @Stevan Stankovic... I just see this answer because I am having the same issue.  It works if the send_file line is changed by return send_file(BytesIO(si.read().encode('utf8')), attachment_filename="export.csv", as_attachment=True, )

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me :

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
# Download shops as CSV
@bp_dashboard.route('/shops', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def shops():
    export_columns = ['type', 'name', 'comment']
    si = StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    cw.writerow(export_columns)
    for shops in shops.query.all():
        cw.writerow([str(getattr(shops, col)) for col in export_columns])
    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=shops.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```